# How to add more items to Priority dropdown in TFS work item

Tags: tfs, process-management

I've created TFS project based on MSF for CMMI process template.

For any type of work item I can only select priority between 1 and 3 which is not enough precise for our process.

How can I widen this priority range, so that I have, for example, priorities 1-8 using process explorer UI?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to edit the work item template.  To do so, export a copy of the work item template using [witexport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253051(VS.80).aspx).  Next you will need to make changes to the allowable values, either in XML or by using the Work Item Template Editor included with [Team Foundation Server Power Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/teamsystem/bb980963.aspx).  Finally, reimport the updated workitem template using [witimport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253163(VS.80).aspx).

Hope that helps.

Comment: I've installed TFS Power Tools, and I'm using Process Template Editor, just I cannot find there where to change that value using UI. 

Probably editing of XML is only way. I already downloaded WIT, and I'll check it out.

Comment: found it

<FIELD name="Priority" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority" type="Integer" reportable="dimension">
  <HELPTEXT>Priority for incorporating the requirement, based on business goals</HELPTEXT> 
  <REQUIRED /> 
- <ALLOWEDVALUES expanditems="true">
  <LISTITEM value="1" /> 
  <LISTITEM value="2" /> 
  <LISTITEM value="3" /> 
  </ALLOWEDVALUES>
  <DEFAULT from="value" value="3" /> 
</FIELD>

It's can be probably set in WIT design mode.

Comment: If you open the .wit file you should be able to find "Priority" in the list of fields.  Double-click on its row to open it, then chose the "Rules" tab.  Double-click on ALLOWEDVALUES to open it, and edit away.  Either way it does the same thing -- I'm a fan of knowing how to do it in XML anyways.

Answer (score 7):

## Adding values to TFS Work Item dropdown the GUI way

1. Install TFS PowerTools
2. Open Visual Studio
3. Go to Tools>Process Editor>Work Item Types>Open WIT from Server
4. Open the WIT that you want to edit
5. The Work Item Type will have three tabs : Fields, Layout, and Workflow
6. If you want to edit the dropdown values of field:Priority go to tab Fields.
7. Double click Priority - a new window opens with 2 tabs: Field Definition and Rules
8. Under Rules tab you will find ALLOWEDVALUES.
9. Edit ALLOWEDVALUES to change values or add new ones to the dropdown.